# How to keep display up to date to monitor options' values of a tk widget

Tags: widget, tcl, tk-toolkit, monitor

I'm developing a tk window to monitor the value of certain options of a widget.
I know I can monitor the latest value of a scalar variable (please allow me to use the term 'scalar' in perl) simply by specifying the variable name as the value of label's `-textvariable` switch. However, when it comes to monitoring widget options, if I use this form, say `.button1 cget -bg` to refer to the background option of a button, I don't know how to update the display of this option's value automatically.

```
label .label1 -textvariable ____  # <-- what should I put here?
```

or should I use another command?

Comment: Actually what I am doing is to design a window which shows a list of pairs of all the supported options and their values of a target widget on the left, and the target widget on the right. I'd like to do various tests/actions to the target widget, and check the current value of all options at the same time. I'm learning tk, and decided to write a script for myself to better understand tk widgets.

Answer (score 0):

When the `-textvariable` option is set to something other than the empty string, it contains the name of a global variable that the label will display *instead of* the value of the `-text` option. To update the displayed value, you just write to the global variable; Tk's built-in machinery handles the rest.

---

*In theory,* you could use a variable trace to emulate the `-textvariable` option using the `-text` option:

```
# Emulating: label .lbl -textvariable foo
label .lbl
trace add variable foo write {apply {{name1 name2 op} {
    # We ignore name2 and op
    upvar 1 $name1 var
    .lbl configure -text $var
}}}
```

However, this is a pain to keep on typing; much more convenient to use the short form!

(Yes, Tk widgets use traces to implement things like `-textvariable`, but they're the C API version of traces so you can't see them from Tcl code. There's a lot of complexity beneath the surface.)

---

If you want to watch something that is part of a composite value (as opposed to a simple variable or array element) then the easiest method is to use a trace.

```
 trace add variable foo write {apply {args {
     global foo displayed_foo_element
     set displayed_foo_element [lindex $foo 1]
 }}}
 label .lbl -textvariable displayed_foo_element
```

Like this, every time the *container* of the thing that you care about (`foo` in the above code) is updated, the trace ensures that the `displayed_foo_element` variable is updated to follow, and the label can just watch that.

You can use much more complex ways of preparing the value for `displayed_foo_element` if you want. Perhaps like this:

```
     set displayed_foo_element "foo\[1\] = '[lindex $foo 1]'"
```

Also, instead of writing to an intermediate variable you can instead update the `-text` option on the widget directly. This option is particularly useful if you also want to adjust other features of the widget at the same time:

```
     if {[lindex $foo 0] >= $CRITICAL_VALUE} {
         set color red
     } else {
         set color black
     }
     .lbl configure -text "foo\[1\] = '[lindex $foo 1]'" -foreground $color
```

Comment: I use `-textvariable var` to monitor a simple scalar variable 'var'. It's simple and neat. But to monitor entities other than a simple scalar variable, like a certain element inside a multi-dimentional list or array, or widget's options that I need to obtain by using tcl commands, I don't know how to do that. btw, thanks for reformating my descriptions.

Comment: The man page of `trace` imformed me that a name which refers to the _container_ is still needed to be provided. Right now the only way I know to access the widget's options is via `<widget> cget` to query a certain option hidden somewhere inside tk. I don't have such a _name_ to use in `trace` format.

Answer (score 0):

To track when a widget option is changed, the easiest way is probably to rename the widget command and put your own proc in its place. That proc just forwards the calls to the original command and then updates the label as necessary:

```
button .button1

rename .button1 __.button1

proc .button1 {method args} {
    set rc [__.button1 $method {*}$args]
    if {$method eq "configure"} {
        .label1 configure -text [__.button1 cget -bg]
    }
    return $rc
}
```

You may need to add some cleanup code to delete your .button1 proc when the widget is destroyed (bind to the  event).

This can also be made prettier when errors occur. But this is the basic method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems that this method applies only when an explicit call to `<widget> configure` is made. Some options got changed in the background when e.g. mouse moves over a widget, or may be as a result of other actions. I need a pane with a list of option-value pair on it that always reflect the latest values.

Comment: Any bindings that change the `-bg` option will do so using the `configure` command. When the mouse moves over the widget, it will show the color specified via the `-activebackground` option. The `-bg` option doesn't change. If you want to report the background color of the widget rather than the value of the `-bg` option, you will have to add a check for the current value of the `-state` option and set label1 to the value of `-bg` or `-activebackground` accordingly.

Comment: Tracing the `-bg` option is just an example. I'd like to design a window with a target widget (perhaps a button) on the right. And as I do various actions to that widget, in the meantime I can always see the latest value of all options that widget supports on the left pane.

Comment: For that purpose the solution I provided will work just fine.